# PictureBox disappears after resize my Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a **MainForms.cs** with **Ribbon**, I want to put a transparent **PictureBox** on the top right of the ribbon (The PictureBox represent my logo).

[image: This is my MainForm with a Logo on the top rigth]

### This is what I have tried:

- I put the **PictureBox** on the top right of the Ribbon
- I set **BackColor** to Transparent.
- I load a PNG image (Containe transparence)
- I set the parent of the image to be the ribbon (and like that the PictureBox will be transparent relative to Ribbon)

Code :

```
InitializeComponent();
pictureBox1.Parent = ribbon1;
```

Until here all is working great.

### **My Problem :**

When I resize my **Form**, the **PictureBox** disappears.

On the **OnPaint** fonction i reset all setting like that :

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    this.Activate();
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    pictureBox1.Show();
    pictureBox1.BringToFront();            
}
```

But nothing makes the Picturebox appear. Please, can you tell me what i missed.

Comment: If this is Winforms, how do you get at a Ribbon? Or is it a MenuStrip?

Comment: The Ribbon i get it from this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application-Cs

Comment: I just put a edit my message, I add a photo of my MainForm with the logo on the top rigth, thanks

Comment: I see. Unfortunalty I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: how are you setting the position of your picturbox on your ribbon

Comment: I use go to my MainForm > Toolbox > i select PictureBox > (drag and drop) > i place it with my mouse on the top of the ribbon.

Comment: What is happening is that your pictureBox's Parent property is being set to null, try setting it back to your ribbon in your OnPaint EventHandler.

Comment: Yes i think about that, i try it but it still "disappears" after resizing the MainForm. Using the consol, i display the coordinates of the "PictureBox", the position doesn't change

Comment: It actually is working when I resize the form larger, but disappears when I shrink it. It actually works if I use the OnResize event

Comment: For me it's disappears for both, enlarge or shrink my MainForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the DLL that you are using and created a small test example. What I noticed is the Parent property of the PictureBox was set to null. By adding the Parent back to the Picturebox in the OnPaint event I was able to get it working if the size of the Form was growing, but would disappear when the Form size was reduced. When I put the same code in the OnResize EventHandler it works like you would expect.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\temp\test.jpg");
        pictureBox1.Parent = ribbon1;
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(this.Width-pictureBox1.Width,10);


    }


    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        if (pictureBox1.Parent == null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Parent = ribbon1;
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(this.Width - pictureBox1.Width, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful!! this is work with OnResize function, thanks a lot Mark